# Undefined index & Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

I am struggling with generating an output if none of the check boxes are selected from the code below.

HTML - Form

```
<label>Item 1:</label><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="Item 1"/>
<label>Item 2:</label><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="Item 2"/>
<label>Item 3:</label><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="Item 3"/>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
foreach ($_REQUEST['selected'] as $key => $selected) {
echo "$selected";           
}         
?>
```

The code outputs the correct value when selected, but generates the "Undefined index: selected in..." & "Invalid argument supplied for foreach():"

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Comment: I don't see any mention of `extra` in your code

Comment: Sorry, I changed extra to selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value is set before using it:

```
<?php
//$_REQUEST['selected'] is set and is array
if(isset($_REQUEST['selected']) && is_array($_REQUEST['selected'])){
    //Loop it
    foreach ($_REQUEST['selected'] as $key=>$selected) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($selected);
    }
}
?>
```

With `Undefined index: extra` that could be some other error, but you think it is this. any ways if you see an `Undefined index` warning that means your trying to access an array key that is undefined e.g not set.

FYI: Note that `$_REQUEST` will accept from $_GET and $_POST, if you are not expecting that value to be set from either, it would be better tobe more specific, so if you use POST in your form then use `$_POST['selected']`

Comment: Thank you very much Lawrence. I am kicking myself because I didn't have the right syntax when I tried to implement it.

Comment: np, easily done. Rule of thumb, if a value is from a global `$_*` always check its set before using. Happy coding